# I need to have a look at all my private pine scripts and filter the scripts for certain words in TRADINGVIEW

Tags: search, download, tradingview-api, organizer

Something like github view will help me
in better organizing the pine script files

For example, if I want to refer any of my old pine scripts for a certain pattern
today, I can browse thru all the files and use a 'find in files'

I want a UI like that of notepad++
or a facility to download all my files locally, so that I can refer them

thank you